# Flutter/Dart Add custom Tap Events for Google Maps Marker

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

How would I add a custom handler for tap events for Google Maps Marker (google_maps_flutter)? I can only see `consumeTapEvents` which doesn't actually take in any functions but only bool. I've thought of using `GestureDetector` but doesn't seem quite right.

What is the standard way of handling events on Google Map's Markers? I'm trying to navigate to a new page upon click.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With the release of version ^0.3.0+1 a new Marker API was introduced which handles markers as widgets (including an onTap() method). This way a Google Map has a `markers:` option which admits a list of Marker objects. Each of the elements can be defined like this:

```
Marker(
  markerId: MarkerId("id"), // a string for marker unique id
  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker(), // options for hues and custom imgs
  position: LatLng(lat, long), // lat and long doubles

  onTap: () {
    //this is what you're looking for!
  }

),
```

Much easier than the former controller approach!

Comment: Do we have access to the `position` of the marker on this `VoidCallback`?

Comment: @mahmoud_eslami in this particular case you are setting the marker (as in getting it from data and setting it on the map), so you know the position and had set it. What would be the case you are referring to? As in tapping on a map and getting coordinates?

Answer (score 8):

You can use onTap or onLongPress option in the map plugin to monitor tap events. Then you can add the marker in following way on the tapped position

```
    final Set<Marker> _markers = {};



 GoogleMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: _center,
          zoom: 13.0,
        ),
        compassEnabled: true,
        tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
        onTap: (latlang){
          if(_markers.length>=1)
            {
              _markers.clear();
            }

          _onAddMarkerButtonPressed(latlang);
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        mapType: mapType,
        markers: _markers,
        onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
      ),
```

where the _onAddMarkerButtonPressed function is

```
 void _onAddMarkerButtonPressed(LatLng latlang) {
loadAddress(latlang);
_latLng = latlang;
 setState(() {
  _markers.add(Marker(
    // This marker id can be anything that uniquely identifies each marker.
    markerId: MarkerId(_lastMapPosition.toString()),
    position: latlang,
    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
      title: address,
    //  snippet: '5 Star Rating',
    ),
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
  ));
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the current release is a **developer preview** at version 0.0.3.  Give it a bit of time to get things working, please!

Comment: All goods :) so the answer would be: there isn't one yet. Correct?

Comment: If it's not listed on the API page, it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
     void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller){
    this._controller = controller;
    controller.onMarkerTapped.add(_onMarkerTapped);
}

void _onMarkerTapped(Marker marker) {
...
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 ... GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        options: GoogleMapOptions(
          ...
        ));
}
```

Comment: `controller.onMarkerTapped.add(_onMarkerTapped);`
for some reason.. this no longer works.

Comment: Lookos to me as if `onMarkerTapped` was not part of the controller anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Make custom object when you creating markers.

```
var map = <String, String> {}; // custom object

for (int i = 0; i < mCrag.length; i++) {
    controller.addMarker(new MarkerOptions(
       icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset('assets/images/down-arrow.png'),
       position: LatLng(double.parse(mCrag[i].lat), double.parse(mCrag[i].lon)),
    )).then((marker) {
         map[marker.id] = mCrag[i].id; // this will return when tap on marker
         return marker;
    });
}

// marker click event
void onMarkerTapped(Marker marker) {
   var selectedMarker = map[marker.id];  // here you will get your id.
   debugPrint(selectedMarker);
   getRoutes(selectedMarker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `flutter_map` package
I tried this and it worked with me.

```dart
addmarker(LatLng postion, String urlimg, String id) {
  marker.add(Marker(
    point: postion,
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
    builder: (context) {
      return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          globals.iduserProfile = id;
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const profileuser(),
            )
          );
        },
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: urlimg,
          imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
            return CircleAvatar(
              radius: 30,
              backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 27,
                backgroundImage: imageProvider,
              )
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ));
  return marker;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like

```
_mapController.onMarkerTapped.add((marker) {
      // your code here
    });
```

Where `_mapController` is an instance of `GoogleMapController` :)

Comment: how to add method in this code..i want to select the location and get that lat,long of the place